# LINQ Error unable to cast object of type 'system.datetime' to type 'system.string'

Tags: linq

I am executing this code where i am getting the error.

Here is the query executed in the asp script. mydateTime contains both date & time value, so i am using CAST to get only date.

```
SELECT CAST(mydateTime AS DATE) AS getdate FROM vTable
```

Here is the code

```
var value = (from r in innerdt.AsEnumerable()
           where r.Field<string>("ggg") == dt.Rows[i][5].ToString()
           select r[0]);
```

Here innerdt is the Datatable & dt is another datatable. I am getting the error in ***select r[0]***

How can i solve the problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `innerdt` table contains a column which is of type `DateTime` but when you query it via `r.Field<string>("ggg")` you want to convert it to a string.

This is where the problem is; method `Field` casts the value of the field to the value of the type you specify so the `Field` method would look something like:

```
public TDest Field<TDest>(this DataRow row, string key)
{
    var value = row[key];
    return (TDest)value; // Here it throws the InvalidCastException
}
```

What you need to do is to convert the `DateTime` to a string after fetching it from the row, like this:

```
var value = (from r in innerdt.AsEnumerable()
             where r.Field<DateTime>("ggg").ToString() == dt.Rows[i][5].ToString()
             select r[0]);
```

As a side note, keep in mind that this will compare dates to milliseconds which may not be what you want. To avoid this either use a format string to make sure that `ToString()` returns only the parts you want or use `ToShortDateString()`.

**EDIT**

As @sloth suggested, a better approach would be to convert `dt.Rows[i][5]` to `DateTime` and then compare the objects using `Date` property; furthermore, you're better off with storing that value in a variable as you'll gain up on readability:

```
var desiredDate = Convert.ToDateTime(td.Rows[i][5]);
var value = (from r in innerdt.AsEnumerable()
             where r.Field<DateTime>("ggg").Date == desiredDate.Date
             select r[0]);
```

Comment: Why not simpy convert `dt.Rows[i][5]` to `DateTime` instead of converting both fields to strings? Then you could also use the `Date` property for the compare, which seems what OP wants.

Comment: @sloth, thank you! I changed the answer to include your suggestion.